# Adding a calculation column to all table in access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database of 250 tables with the same structure. I would need to add a calculated column to all of the tables. However I recieve a run time error 3191 and I just can not figure out what is wrong. Anyone an idea?

Thank you
M.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim td As DAO.TableDef
Dim Fld As DAO.Field2

Set db = CurrentDb()

    For Each td In db.TableDefs
        Set Fld = td.CreateField("Stock", dbInteger)
        Fld.Expression = "[CS]-[RS]-[TBO]"
        td.Fields.Append Fld
    Set Fld = Nothing
    Next

Set td = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html). -- Also, *250 tables with the same structure* is a bad idea, and you should correct that ASAP, because at some point you will have to anyway.

Comment: Andre, to be honest I decided to use access only fo modifying and filtering the data to be able to export it to excel afterwards. Originally I had 250 txt files (remaining different types of stock per day on the level of item). I hoped I would be able to connect the data to one table where I  would recieve calculated stock per each day and item. unfortunatelly I got stuck on the start - calculating field.

Comment: Could you not just loop through your tables and export a query that does the calculation?